In Lean 4 prover, how to include a constructor into the search scope of a tactic?
I'm translating a soundness proof of system F- from Rocq to Lean 4.
Here is part of the relevant Rocq code:

(** Well-formedness of a pre-type T in an environment E:
  all the type variables of T must be bound via a
  subtyping relation in E. This predicates implies
  that T is a type *)

Inductive wft : env -> typ -> Prop :=
  | wft_top : forall E,
      wft E typ_top
  | wft_var : forall U E X,
      binds X (bind_sub U) E ->
      wft E (typ_fvar X)
  | wft_arrow : forall E T1 T2,
      wft E T1 ->
      wft E T2 ->
      wft E (typ_arrow T1 T2)
  | wft_all : forall L E T1 T2,
      wft E T1 ->
      (forall X, X \notin L ->
        wft (E & X ~<: T1) (T2 open_tt_var X)) ->
      wft E (typ_all T1 T2).

...

Hint Constructors type term wft ok okt value red.

Namely, Hint Constructor wft enable wft to be used automaticlly by the upcoming tactics as a lemma.
When I tried to convert it into Lean, LLM tried the following option:

/- Well-formedness of a pre-type T in an environment E -/
@[constructor]
inductive wft : env → Typ → Prop where
  | wft_top : (E : env) →
      wft E Typ.typ_top
  | wft_var : (U : Typ) → (E : env) → (X : Var) →
      E.contains X ∧ E.find! X = bind.bind_sub U →
      wft E (Typ.typ_fvar X)
  | wft_arrow : (E : env) → (T1 T2 : Typ) →
      wft E T1 →
      wft E T2 →
      wft E (Typ.typ_arrow T1 T2)
  | wft_all : (L : Std.HashSet Var) → (E : env) → (T1 T2 : Typ) →
      wft E T1 →
      (∀ X, X ∉ L →
        wft (E.insert X (bind.bind_sub T1)) (open_tt_var T2 X)) →
      wft E (Typ.typ_all T1 T2)

unfortunately the attribute @[constructor] cannot be found anywhere, apparently because it is abandoned in Lean 4.
What's the easiest way to do the same in Lean 4, without explicitly calling it every time for each new tactic defined?

What does it mean to be used automatically as a lemma (especially since this is an inductive and not a lemma)?  Do you have an example?  Is this automatic in Coq for any possible tactic?  I don’t think that can be done in Lean.  But you can label it to be used automatically for certain types of tactics like simp (but simp lemmas are equalities so I don’t think this fits this use case).  Also you may want to check it is not already used automatically in the settings you are thinking. For example simp uses some auto-generated theorems about your inductive automatically.

For what it is worth, here is a list of all attributes in Lean and Mathlib: https://seasawher.github.io/mathlib4-help/attributes/

Basically Hint constructors foo : db. adds all constructors for type foo in the hint database db (as lemmas). After that, many automation tactics, primarily auto, can pick up these constructors during proof search. By default, if you do not specify the database, the hints get added to core, the default one (@tribbloid note that in general this is discouraged, it is encouraged to at least explicitly name the database, and ideally not use core as this will "pollute" all automation).

I don’t think this question translates well to Lean.  You can leave it up just in case, but maybe it is better to ask a new question when you get to a situation where you want to automatically pick up this inductive’s constructors via a tactic and that tactic doesn’t pick it up.  If instead you are defining your own custom tactics, then maybe you could see if other tactics like aesop could help. Aesop lets you define rule sets and has been used e.g. to implement tactics checking if a function is continuous by checking that it is constructed from continuous parts, etc

https://github.com/leanprover-community/aesop  I would look here and see if this fits your needs.  In particular, there is @[aesop safe [constructors, cases]].

I don't remember @[constructor] in Lean 3 — are you sure it was abandoned in Lean 4? It seems much more likely this hallucinated by the LLM.
